# Firestore - Python getting only the value from array field with 'array_contains'

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Google Firestore to fetch some RSS feeds. I have a dict called "Haber Listesi"
When I'm using a where query to compare with my dict, Query returns whole array that contain the value.
And if there are more data which is equal, query returns same array again.

How can i get only value that array contains or get that array once?

```
for hbr in Haber_Listesi["Haber"]:
    docs += db.collection('Haberler Listesi').where('Haber', 'array_contains', hbr).get()
```

Comment: Does `Haber_Listesi` contain unique values? And what do you mean with: `Query returns whole array that contain the value. And if there are more data which is equal, query returns same array again.`? Could you share an example of this? It could be that you have to mange the Haber_Listesi[] before going to query.

Comment: Yes, it has unique values. I mean; for ex. When i run this query for "hbr" value, the query returns the document which "hbr" belongs to. But I want to get only "hbr" value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cloud Firestore SDKs you always retrieve full documents, not certain values. The only way to retrieve a subset of each document is through the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api).

All REST API endpoints exist under the base URL https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/. The best way to begin experimenting with the REST API is to use the [API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/?apix=true), which automatically generates Google Identity OAuth 2.0 tokens and allows you to examine the API.

Maybe you might want to change the approach on how are you retrieving this information. Even you can think on duplicate certain data ([denormalization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA) - this tutorial talks about Firebase Realtime Database, but the principle are the same for Firestore) in your database, which is quite common in NoSQL databases. This will depend on the whole workflow you have and your app architecture. I will share this with you about [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques).

There you can find concrete data modeling techniques and patterns, a list of the particular systems that, the author, had in mind while working on  the article, and conceptual techniques as: denormalization, aggregates, application side joins, atomic aggregates, enumerable keys, dimensionality reduction, index tables among many other topics.